# POSTFIX/DOVECOT smtp timeout connecting to linux server

Tags: laravel, dovecot

I'm trying to set up a VPS server and having problems with email.

I cannot seem to get the SMTP to work on the website. I'm using 127.0.0.1 and tried ports 25, 465 and 587. However, they all time out.

I've tried to connect using Outlook and it returns the same problem timeout with the SMTP server. I've tried with TLS and STARTTLS, but neither connects.

I've checked the firewall and there are rules to allow the connections.

I've tried to test using telnet but not of the ports answer, it says connected but nothing else.

I'm using dovecot and postfix on the server. I've verified the dovecot email and password.

The site is laravel 10.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem with a map file that caused the smtpd service to fail.